# How to map keystrokes to a command?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

How to map keystrokes to a command in vim?

For example, I would like to create a custom command `Cmt`, and I could use it to comment out lines 10-20 like this: `:10,20Cmt`

I have tried something like `:command -range Cmt <line1>gg O ...` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `:normal!` command:

```
command -range Cmt normal! <line1>ggO
```

Commands take everything to the right of the name (`Cmt`) and runs it as an ex command:

```
command -nargs=1 LetX let g:x = '<args>'
```

Substitutions are made on the command before it's executed.  So, running `10Cmt` will execute `:normal! 10ggO`.